# How to get matplotlib bar chart to match numeric count in python terminal

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

My main objective is to be consistent with both my numeric output and my visual output. However, I can't seem to get to them to match.

Here is my setup using python 3.x:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2,
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],columns=['Expo'])
```

Followed by my setup for the bar chart in matplotlib:

```
x = df['Expo']
N = len(x)
y = range(N)
width = 0.125
plt.bar(x, y, width, color="blue")
fig = plt.gcf();
```

A Nice pretty graph produced:[image]

However, using this snippet code to check and see what the actual numeric counts of both classes are...

```
print("Class 1: "+str(df['Expo'].value_counts()[1]),"Class 2: "+str(df['Expo'].value_counts()[2]))
```

I get the below:

> Class 1: 85 Class 2: 70

Since I have 155 records in the data frame, numerically this makes sense. Having a single bar in the bar chart be at 155 does not.

I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Explain yourself better, because I see that the results you get are correct.

Comment: You want it to show up like a stack?

Comment: The numeric output for class 1 shows 85. However, the graph shows approximately 115.

The numeric output for class 2 shows 70. However, the graph shows approximately 155.

I want the numeric values and the graphical values to be the same.

Currently, they don't seem to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this is what you're after:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame([ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2,
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],columns=['Expo'])

# Count number of '1' and '2' elements in df
N1, N2 = len(df[df['Expo'] == 1]), len(df[df['Expo'] == 2])
width = 0.125
# Plot the lengths in x positions [1, 2]
plt.bar([1, 2], [N1, N2], width, color="blue")
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
```

Which produces

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use a histogram,

```
plt.hist(df["Expo"])
```

[image]

or specifying the bins

```
plt.hist(df["Expo"], bins=[0.5,1.5,2.5], ec="k")
plt.xticks([1,2])
```

[image]